# How do I set CMake policy and property on an external project added using ExternalProject_Add

Tags: cmake, external-project

I have a cmake project that uses an external project using CMake's ExternalProject_Add feature. Is there a way to set policy and property on the external project?

I would like following policy and property that is set in my project to be forwarded also to external project so that static multi-threaded windows runtime libraries are used instead of dynamic ones.

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0091 NEW)
set(CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")
```

Comment: Did you already tried to add them to the `CMAKE_ARGS` variable on the `ExternalProject_Add` command, e.g. `-DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091:STRING=NEW -DCMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY:STRING=MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>` ?

Comment: was not aware policy can be set this way. Tested this now and worked perfectly! can you add this as answer so I can mark as accepted answer. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add those settings to the `CMAKE_ARGS` variable of the `ExternalProject_Add` command, e.g.

```
ExternalProject_Add(<you_name_it>
  ...
  CMAKE_ARGS
           -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091:STRING=NEW 
           -DCMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY:STRING=MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>
           ...
)
```