# CMAKE with both a toolchain file and cmake_policy

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I have a chicken-and-egg situation.  I am using vcpkg, which requires me to set a cmake toolchain file from the command line.  But I also have some `cmake_policy` statements which need to be set in CMakeLists.txt prior to the toolchain file.

Here is how cmake is called:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-linux ..
```

But the projects uses some packages which requires the following two policies immediately after `CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED`:

```
CMAKE_POLICY ( SET CMP0003 NEW ) # libs linked via full path
CMAKE_POLICY ( SET CMP0011 NEW ) # push/pop instead of no_policy_scope
```

**My question:**  Is there a way to specify the toolchain from within `CMakeLists.txt` -- presumably immediately after having set the two cmake policies -- instead of at the command line?

The warning I get which I'd like to solve is this one:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:221 (_add_executable):
  Policy CMP0003 should be set before this line.  Add code such as
    if(COMMAND cmake_policy)
      cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)
    endif(COMMAND cmake_policy)
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to set the policies from the command line as well:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0003=NEW \
      -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0011=NEW \
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake \
      -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-linux \
      ..
```

See [How do I set CMake policy and property on an external project added using ExternalProject_Add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398627/how-do-i-set-cmake-policy-and-property-on-an-external-project-added-using-extern)