# Assimp Cmake ExternalProject statically link MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, assimp

I'm attempting to add [assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) to a cmake build. I need for the library to build statically, statically linking msvc (/MT for release and /MTd for debug). There does not appear to be a specific cmake option to enable/disable this for assimp itself. I have tried the following to force the library to statically link msvc:

`set(CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")`

```
if(MSVC)
    add_compile_options(
        $<$<CONFIG:>:/MT> #---------|
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/MTd> #---|-- Statically link the runtime libraries
        $<$<CONFIG:Release>:/MT> #--|
    )   
endif()
```

Neither of which seem to have any effect, as the library continues to build as /MD or /MDd. Is there a specific flag for assimp to enable or disable static linking msvc that i just cannot find? If not how could I go about accomplishing this? Below is the relevent section of my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
# SETUP ASSIMP
set(libAssimp assimp)
ExternalProject_Add(${libAssimp}
PREFIX          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/${libAssimp}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/assimp/assimp.git
GIT_TAG         v5.0.1
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
UPDATE_COMMAND  ""
CMAKE_ARGS      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/installs/${libAssimp}
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_ALL_IMPORTERS_BY_DEFAULT:BOOL=OFF
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_ALL_EXPORTERS_BY_DEFAULT:BOOL=OFF
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS:BOOL=OFF
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_FBX_IMPORTER:BOOL=ON
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_OBJ_IMPORTER:BOOL=ON
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_OBJ_EXPORTER:BOOL=ON
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_ZLIB:BOOL=ON
                -DASSIMP_LIBRARY_SUFFIX:STRING=
                -DLIBRARY_SUFFIX:STRING=
                -DCMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX:STRING=
                -DASSIMP_INJECT_DEBUG_POSTFIX:BOOL=OFF
                -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF
)

set(ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/installs/${libAssimp})
add_library(ASSIMP_LIBRARY STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(ASSIMP_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}assimp${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})

add_library(IRRXML_LIBRARY STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(IRRXML_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}IrrXML${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})

add_library(ZLIB_LIBRARY STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
ZLIB_LIBRARY 
PROPERTIES 
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}zlibstatic${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_MINSIZEREL ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}zlibstatic${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}zlibstatic${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}zlibstaticd${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
)
```

**UPDATE**

I believe I may have figured this out. Although I had tried adding `CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY` and `MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY` to `CMAKE_FLAGS` previously to no avail...I'm thinking cmake may have been caching the original values as I just tried downloading assimp independently of my superbuild, insured the cache was cleared and built using the above flags, and VS is showing as `/MT`. Will report back once I have confirmed this is working in my superbuild with `ExternalProject_Add`.

**UPDATE002**

Alright, IDK how I had this working in my above explanation, but I'm unable to duplicate it going through the same process as before. Cleared cmake cache, used all the same options, stuck on /MD again.

Answer (score 1):

The `CMakeLists.txt` file for assimp has a minimum version of 3.10 (as of this post). Therefore the `MSVC` flags were being ignored. Adding the below to the projects `CMakeLists.txt` file works when building the project directly:

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0091 NEW)
set(CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")
```

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398627), when loading via `ExternalProject_Add` you must pass the parameters using the `CMAKE_ARGS` parameter like such (last two args):

```
set(libAssimp assimp)
ExternalProject_Add(${libAssimp}
PREFIX          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/${libAssimp}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/assimp/assimp.git
GIT_TAG         v5.0.1
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
UPDATE_COMMAND  ""
CMAKE_ARGS      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/installs/${libAssimp}
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_ALL_IMPORTERS_BY_DEFAULT:BOOL=OFF
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_ALL_EXPORTERS_BY_DEFAULT:BOOL=OFF
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS:BOOL=OFF
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_FBX_IMPORTER:BOOL=ON
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_OBJ_IMPORTER:BOOL=ON
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_OBJ_EXPORTER:BOOL=ON
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_ZLIB:BOOL=ON
                -DASSIMP_LIBRARY_SUFFIX:STRING=
                -DLIBRARY_SUFFIX:STRING=
                -DCMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX:STRING=
                -DASSIMP_INJECT_DEBUG_POSTFIX:BOOL=OFF
                -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF
                -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091:STRING=NEW
                -DCMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY:STRING=MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>
)
```